# Error while building Mapnik (a c++ program)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, scons, mapnik

I am trying to build Mapnik from source on my local Linux Mint 21.2 machine ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik).

When compiling, it stops due to an error.

```
include/mapnik/filesystem.hpp:38:21: error: expected namespace name
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
               ~~~~~^
include/mapnik/filesystem.hpp:39:25: error: no type named 'error_code' in namespace 'std'
using error_code = std::error_code;
                   ~~~~~^
src/fs.cpp:40:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fs'
    return fs::exists(filepath);
           ^
```

There are many more later errors following from these, but this is where it starts.

Edit: There are also numerous warnings before about **unary functions being deprecated**.

```
In file included from mason_packages/.link/include/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:47:
mason_packages/.link/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:131:33: warning: 'unary_function<std::type_index, unsigned long>' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        struct hash_base : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};
                                ^
```

#### Here is what I did:

I tried following instructions from the [Mapnik Install Guide for Linux](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation)

They are specifically warning about needing a compiler that is up to date with the **C++14** Standard. So I suspect it has something to do with me having the wrong compiler.

I successfully added the `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` PPA in order to install recent compiler versions. But: When I try to install `gcc-6`, it says that there is no such package, but it is referenced by another package. I am confused. I figure `gcc-6` is too old to be in the PPA anymore, as the current version is `gcc-12`, but maybe it was current at the time the Install Wiki was written.

So I figured that my current versions of `gcc`, `clang` and `g++` might be recent enough because that install page was last updated in 2020.

These are my versions:

- `gcc -v`: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
- `g++ -v`: apparently synonym to `gcc`
- `clang -v`: Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1

So my question is: Are the above errors introduced by using an inappropriate compiler which does not understand these lines?

Therefore, I think it is a c++ question, because some of you might know this kind of error.

Comment: Sadly `std::filesystem` first appears in C++17 so it looks like the need for C++14 is incorrect. GCC11 is recent enough to have  `filesystem` support, but you may have to ask for C++17 with `-std=c++17~ added to the compiler command line.

Comment: Side note: `g++` is the C++ compiler that's part of  the GCC toolchain, so it's not quite a synonym for the C compiler `gcc`. They are two different tools that come in both come in the same GCC, Gnu Compiler Collection, box. Mixing the two up can lead to tears of frustration.

Comment: thanks a lot! this really helps me. Also, now I understand that gcc is for C whereas g++ is for C++ and located inside the GnuCompilerCollection which is short gcc. Wow.

When compiling it with `make`, how do I add the `-std=c++-17` flag? I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: Depends on the makefile, but there's usually a `CXXFLAGS=<bunch of options>` line in there you can add more compiler options to.

Comment: Uppercase GCC is the Gnu Compiler Collection. the lowercase `gcc` program is, or at least used to be, Gnu C Compiler. Once upon a time when gcc was all there was things were simple, but when it started picking up other compilers they had to change the name, but they couldn't change it much for fear of mass confusion.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, running it with the c++17 standard did not fix the issue. I will edit my question to add my additional findings.  
And to the previos answer: you are right, in this case the whole thing is built with `SCons` (python) and there is a `configure.py` file that lets you specify all kind of flags including one for the standard used.

Comment: Do you know if the `std::filesystem` thing is only supported in c++17 and not in c++14 standard? Because if this was the case, we would have an easy explanation: During build, my config file gets reconfigured automatically back to c++14 standard.

Although i can not believe this is the cause because this would be functionality breaking bug not just for me and for sure would be fixed very soon. so I will try to find the root of it

Comment: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) practically screams *since C++17* in the title.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like some evidence to me to open an issue on the Mapnik GitHub repo. Thank you for following along so far.
I can even see in the output that the compiler (in this case it is called `clang++` for some reason is being called with the `-std=c++14` flag, now that I knew what to look for.

Comment: why did you tag #scons ?

Comment: because mapnik is built using scons. Please let me know if this is off topic, then I will remove it.

Comment: This page is often useful in figuring out when things are added, who supports it, and how to get to it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: I also found that page, but it was an information overkill for my non c++ savvy brain. But it is actually helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully managed to avoid the errors completely by compiling with `C++17` standard instead of the default `C++14` standard.

How to set this flag during configuration:

```
./configure CXX_STD="17"
```

See the whole struggle in [Issue 4405 on Mapnik Repo](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/4405). To get to a functional complete build, additional patches are needed unfortunately.